# How to setup RDP on a System running windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I want to set up a RDP on a 32-bit computer running windows 7 ultimate and then connect a VPS to the system. Please can someone help me any guide?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following guides could be helpful. Please check this out:

https://www.howtogeek.com/131961/how-to-access-windows-remote-desktop-over-the-internet/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1LIkQUr0_Q